# Pass an array variable to a function

Tags: angularjs

I have two functions inside controller:

```
$scope.historyMemberInit = function(fkhouseid) {
  $scope.fkhouseid = fkhouseid;
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'House/member_list.php',
    data: {fkhouseid:$scope.fkhouseid}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.memberList = response.data;
    $scope.remains($scope.memberList);      
    console.log(response);
  });
};
$scope.historyHouseInit = function(fkhouseid) {
  $scope.fkhouseid = fkhouseid;
  $http({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'House/house_list.php',
    data: {fkhouseid:$scope.fkhouseid}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.houseList = response.data;
    $scope.remains($scope.houseList);
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

It will load data from database for two different tables. I want to call `$scope.remains();` function inside each function:

```
$scope.remains = function(list) {   
  $scope.unList = list;   
  $scope.limit = 15;
  var stubs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.limit - $scope.unList.length; i++)
    stubs.push(i);    
  return stubs;
}
```

Im getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

How can I pass list variable to the `remains` function?

**EDIT**
Here is what i get from `console.log($scope.houseList);` same as for `console.log(response.data)`:

[image]

Comment: are you facing any issue in the current code?

Comment: Your current code seems to work fine. What's the issue

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy can you please update the question with data you getting in the list as well?

Comment: Please try to debug and check the value of response and response.data.

Comment: Your list is not instantiated/defined.

Comment: response.data should be a list. Please just check once....may be it is something else

Comment: @NiteshRana I added data i get from the response.data

Comment: @RakeshBurbure I added data. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.limit - $scope.unList.length; i++)
```

assing to a variable and compare,

```
var difference = $scope.limit - $scope.unList.length;
```

and then,

```
  for (var i = 0; i < difference ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Push `Response.data` into some array and then send to function: 
(because your response is not an array, it is an Object)

```
var arrayObject=[];
arrayObject.push(response.data[0]);
then call function:
$scope.remains = function(arrayObject) {   
  $scope.unList = arrayObject;   
  $scope.limit = 15;
  var stubs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.limit - $scope.unList.length; i++)
    stubs.push(i);    
  return stubs;
}
```